# How to get JSON data from server storage to client using Meteor.Call and update the return data synchronously in the template?

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

I have a file named countries.json in the root/private folder. I want to show all country names in a multi select box within the "newCampaignForm" template. **getCountryList** method on the server return the json object  to the client. 
The ***console log*** always show the returned object and sometime print **undefined** and then the object. 
 However, the select box usually do not show the country list; only once on every server restart when console log doesn't print undefined at first. **How** to solve this problem?

Reading various QA here, I guess I have to make the function synchronous using **Meteor.wrapAsync** function but I find it very hard to write Meteor.wrapAsync in proper way that works. As a *beginner* , I find it hard to follow  the meteor docs which lacks easy examples and due to my confusion about callback functions.
 
 If Meteor.wrapAsync is the solution here, then please re-write my code below  that works. This is my 1st question here. Thanks a lot!

```js
//CLIENT SIDE CODE

Template.newCampaignForm.onRendered(function() {

    Meteor.call('getCountryList',function(err,result){
         
                    Session.set('cData',result);

                    });
}

Template.newCampaignForm.helpers({

  countryList:function() {
 
      console.log(Session.get('cData'));
      return Session.get('cData');

        }

    });
    

// SERVER SIDE CODE

getCountryList:function () {
    var country = {};
   country = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('countries.json'));
 return country;
 }


// Loop on Template

<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select form-control" id="targetCountries" multiple tabindex="1">

   {{#each countryList}}

    <option value = "{{name}}" > {{name}} </option>

    {{/each}}

</select>
```

Comment: What does the JSON result look like? Is it an array of value like `['germany', 'france', 'spain', 'usa']`? Otherwise can't loop via `#each`. Instead of using event `onRendered` try `onCreated`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created

[this very simple MeteorPad Playground](http://meteorpad.com/pad/3PvmG8cXFyHQvpvCP/Playground_Get_select_values_from_server_side_json_with_session_var)

and

[this MeteorPad Playground with ReactiveVar](http://meteorpad.com/pad/oY7nSEgENWk9puAdc/Playground_Get_select_values_from_server_side_json)

and this

[Gist Example](https://gist.github.com/TomFreudenberg/2893d4450e29c245fe3a)

as an answer.

Remaining to your question:

1. Maybe your JSON is not a valid array
2. Event is `rendered` not `onRendered`
3. When countryList should be an array, you used the wrong naming `{{name}}` instead of `{{this}}` on template (this depends a bit of your JSON I do not know yet)

Comment: Although it is better to use a reactive variable, I don't know if it really solves the user's problem, as [Session variables work just as well in your meteorpad example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/Aad39FNXeCvQizbuT/Copy%20of%20Playground_Get_select_values_from_server_side_json%20%282%29). I'm guessing the problem comes from somewhere else

Comment: Then again, it shows a working solution :) with a proper JSON string, which is maybe the issue here

Comment: Thanks @tomFreudenberg  & BraveKenny for the fast response. :) However, the solution didn't work, I have already tried with ReactiveVar but to my best guess the problem arise as it involves FILE I/O operation in the server. I already mentioned above that I always get the returned object in the log with 1st output printed as undefined. Then if I restart my meteor server, I get the value in the form too but not in 1st time load.
The json data on file looks like this :  [link] (https://gist.github.com/Keeguon/2310008)

Comment: Have a look at the first simple example again. I have updated that to your JSON structure. Be aware that also `name` and `code` should be written inside (") like `"name": "Country"` and `"code": "Code"`

Comment: Hi, I made you a gist with all files and infos. That sould show and work for you. [Gist Example](https://gist.github.com/TomFreudenberg/2893d4450e29c245fe3a)

Comment: Finally solved the mystery! The _Chosen jQuery  plugin_ I was using for the select box can not load data from AJAX call (or any remote data that populate after the form is rendered).
 So just replaced chosen with _Select2 jquery plugin_ which natively support AJAX call & dynamic data loading and now everything is working fine. Thanks a lot for your time & support.